# SASS Conditional: set Property Value based on another Property Value

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I'm using slideout.js for a mobile nav and upon each page load, the menu flashes on the screen for a moment and disappears until the hamburger button is toggled. This doesn't happen if I set the div containing the nav to display: none, but of course when I open the menu, none of the links are displayed.

My question is, using Sass, can I create a conditional that performs the following logic on two separate classes:

```
if .slideout-menu is not set to display: block
```

then

```
.mobile-nav should be set to display: none;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can't react to changes that happen on a page without JS help besides from pseudo-classes, so unfortunately you can't target it that way. `slideout.js` adds classes to style different states of the slide-out menu so try targeting those.

Try something like this:

```
.slideout-menu .mobile-nav {
   display: none;
}
.slideout-open .slideout-menu .mobile-nav {
     display: block; // or whichever display property you need
}
```

Going off of the CSS states in index.css from https://slideout.js.org/

Comment: Thanks, a slight variation of this worked perfectly. I was overcomplicating it.